# Are there any mechanical effects of being at zero Willpower?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

In the World of Darkness core book, they state the following about being at zero Willpower:

> Characters with no Willpower points left are exhausted — physically, mentally and emotionally. They've used up their reserves of determination and tend to be listless and depressed. (p. 95)

Other than obviously being unable to spend Willpower on die rolls, are there any mechanical effects to this condition?

Comment: If you've got access to the **God Machine Chronicle**, this might be a good place to use a Condition.

Comment: Does nWoD have social combat like Exalted? Being tapped out on WP in Exalted basically means people can get you to do anything short of an Unacceptable Order with social attacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I looked through the Core Rulebook and did not find any mechanical effects related to having zero temporary Willpower. I think that not being able to use Willpower for any of its game effects (extra defense, extra dice, etc.) is penalty enough.

Comment: It might be worth noting that Changeling: The Lost contains rules for being brought to *negative* Willpower due to dream combat (p. 198), but again lists no ill effects for being at zero.